# How to trigger a PersistentView update externally

Tags: scala, akka, akka-persistence

According to [the docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/persistence.html#Updates), triggering a view update externally is supposed to work like this:

`view ! Update(await = true|false)`

sending and waiting seems not to work though:

```
view ! Update(await = true) // repeat x times does not help either
Thread.sleep(2000)
val getState = view ? GetState
```

the view state is not being updated.

asking does not work either - there is no answer to `Update` and the `Await` times out:

```
val getUpdate = v ? Update(await = true)
val updated = Await.result(getUpdate, 10 seconds)
val getState = view ? GetState
```

IIUC, processing of `Update` messages is performed by `PersistentView#State#stateReceive`. Its reception is not logged and I dont know how I can verify the reception and processing. `Update` msgs dont reach the `receive` overridden in my `PersistentView`.

what does work is setting a very short refresh interval in a `.conf`:

```
persistence.view.auto-update-interval = 100ms
```

The debug log shows that the Journal is updating the view:

`... a.p.i.e.InMemoryJournalStorage akka://entityViewSpec/user/JournalStorage - received handled message GetJournalEntriesExceptDeleted(ea-ZleUNl1a3N,1,1,9223372036854775807) from Actor[akka://entityViewSpec/temp/$o]`

I dont see this log entry when sending `Update` and waiting

after a short sleep, the view is updated, as expected.

```
Thread.sleep(200)
val getState = view ? GetState
```

So how do I trigger a view update externally without running autoupdates all the time?

Akka 2.4.8

Thank you

**EDIT**

My mistake was quite simple - not giving the initial msg enough time to be persisted - the `Update` call has been received at a time when the relevant events were not available from the store yet. The autoupdate setting waited for 100ms before updating. On my local machine with in-mem persistence I need to allow about 50ms before dispatching the `Update`. Then give the system some time to fetch and apply the events:

not working:

```
actor ! MyCommand
view ! Update(await = true)
Thread.sleep(500)
val getState = view ? GetState
```

working:

```
actor ! MyCommand
Thread.sleep(50)
view ! Update(await = true)
Thread.sleep(500)
val getState = view ? GetState
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to recreate your issue but mine view is refreshed :/
Check my example: https://github.com/kpbochenek/akka-playground

Run `MyPersistentView.scala`

auto-update is off

I can see in logs(View actor receives messages persisted by persistent actor):

```
00:11:35.325 [pw-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] INFO  com.kpbochenek.MyActor - persisted! AAAAAAAA
00:11:35.326 [pw-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9] INFO  com.kpbochenek.MyActor - persisted! 11111111
00:11:37.254 [pw-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] INFO  com.kpbochenek.MyView - VIEW READ AAAAAAAA
00:11:37.255 [pw-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] INFO  com.kpbochenek.MyView - VIEW READ 11111111
```

Comment: Thanks, kpbochenek. Your test helped me see my misunderstanding. please see the edit